# DC offset cancellation

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, receiver, detector, dc-offset

I am working on THz detector and was going through research papers.

In the receiver stage a preamplifier is used in the circuit shown below.

Why can't we directly use the amplifier?

How does the dummy structure used in the preamplifier offer DC offset cancellation as mentioned in the paper?

[image: reseach paper]

[image: circuit diagram]

Comment: Preamplifiers are used to improve SNR. There may be other reasons why the author specified a preamp also.

Comment: I don't quite understand this amplifier - is it trying to rectify the signal? Usually to make something like a differential amplifier, one of the amplifier's inputs would go to M3 and M4, and the other one would go to M5 and M6. (in fact you wouldn't have the transistors in pairs like that - you'd make one transistor twice as big)

Comment: @user253751 The idea is not to amplify the signal, but to generate another signal depending on the "intensity" of the incoming signal. M1 and M2 are chip-level identical transistors, and C1 and C2 are chip-level identical capacitors. C1 (C2) causes a phenomenon called "self-mixing" and produces DC as well as *possibly* distorted copy of the input signal at the drain of M1 (M2). If the DC offset is enough then it'll bias M4 (M3). Since the input signals are differential there's going to be zero AC component at the common-drain junction, and a DC current will flow and drop a voltage across M9.

Comment: I understood how this works but still couldn't figure out how M5-M6 pair helps to reduce (or to remove) the internally-generated (how???) DC offset.

Comment: @RohatKılıç It makes the circuit more symmetrical. Consider that if both sides of the preamplifier are perfectly identical, then Vdet and Vref are the same voltage (no DC offset, when considered as a differential signal). The only difference comes from the input signal. When the input signal is 0 there is again no difference.

Comment: @user253751Also is the Vref just the ac ground as the current is zero though the dummy structure?

Comment: @Andyaka Is it why the preamplifier is used in subthreshold region that contributes to less noise (increases SNR)?

Answer (score 2):

The right side of the preamplifier is identical to the left side except the input is permanently connected to ground (0V). Therefore it should output the same voltage which the left side outputs when the input is 0V. When considering the preamplifier's output as a differential signal, that means the output is 0V (same voltage on both sides) when the input is 0V.

Of course both sides should also be manufactured identically, placed close together on the same chip, to make sure they are as closely matched as possible.

If the circuit was not designed like this, it would (presumably) need some other way to determine which voltage the preamplifier outputs when it is at 0V. One method is capacitor coupling (a high-pass filter which reduces low frequencies and completely blocks DC); another method is chopper stabilization (which uses the left half to calculate its own reference voltage, continually switching it between "reference voltage mode" and "actual amplification mode"); another method is to add a potentiometer and tell the technician how to adjust it :)

Comment: How can the preamplifier output be differential?

Comment: @prashanth it has two output wires and the signal is the difference between the two wires, is it not?

Comment: The output signals cannot be differential but the opamp amplifies the difference of input signals. Also, here Vref is VDD and Vdet depends on the input.

Comment: @prashanth the "subthreshold preamplifier" has two outputs and the signal is the difference between them. The "three-stage folded cascode amplifier" has one output, at least in the drawing.